# vba loop to add 12 consecutive months worth of data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, vba7

I am attempting to create vba code to add the values of twelve consecutive months of data to a cell, then increment each month to be added by one, so that the code shifts to sum 12 months that include the newer month of data. For example, the first cell that contains a sum adds data from sheets 0220 to sheet 0121, where the sheet names are dates. The next cell contains the sum for sheets 0320 to sheet 0221.

The complication is that the sheets are from an external workbook. I wrote some code, but it is not correct yet, and I was wondering if my loops are on the right track.

```
Sub LoopValues()

Dim i As Integer

' get & set excel wkb
Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet

Set wkb = Excel.Workbooks('C:\file\[FileName.xlsx])
Set wks = wkb.Worksheets()

Dim temp As Double

Dim startVal As Double


' Increment sheet index via nested for loop to sum for a 12 month period
' Sum cells
' deposit value


For j = 0 To 11 Step 1

    startVal = 220 + j * 100  ' shifts summation

    For i = 0 To 11 Step 1 ' increment months through selection twelve continous months
        Set wks = wkb.Worksheets(startVal + i * 100)
        temp+= wks.Range("AA208").Value
    Next i
    
    Range("J99" + i).Value = temp
Next j
```

End Sub

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble following exactly what is going on with your desired situation.  Do you have images (or mock-up) that you can share, which won't breach any confidentiality?

Comment: I do not, but I can include an image of my messy notes showing the situation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If those month sheets got exactly the same estructure, maybe you can use formulas to sum up trought different sheets same range. But the data would need to be always in the same range, whatever it is. Length of data does not matter, but position of data does. Oh, and the sheets would need to be sorted consecutive( 0120, 0220, 0320....0121,0221,0321...and so on)

Comment: The sheets do have the same structure, so I am always summing values with the same cell reference. The complication with using formulas arose when I was trying to find a way to avoid referencing the worksheet each time and manually changing the cell references.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go is as follows: create a `Do While ... Loop` that keeps trying to access sheets named `mmdd` starting at `0220`, retrieve the value from Range("AA208") (assuming you always want the value from this particular cell), and store that value in an `Array`. We will do this until we meet a sheet name for which no sheet exists.

Now we should have all the values we want and can simply loop through the array, get the `SUM` for each subset of 12 consecutive values and assign it to Range("J99"), Range("J100") etc. in your ActiveWorkbook.

Code as follows, with comments on what it does. One nice thing to realize is that VBA automatically converts input for `DateSerial()` into sensible output. E.g. `DateSerial(2022, 13, 1)` will be understood as `1/1/2023`. This makes it very easy to construct the strings for the worksheet names.

Let me know if you experience any difficulties with implementation.

```
Sub LoopValues()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook, wbOpen As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsName As String, wsExists As Boolean
Dim counter As Integer, i As Integer

'set your wbs (active and one to open
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbOpen = Application.Workbooks.Open("data.xlsx")

'string like "0220", apparently your first sheet
wsName = Format(DateSerial(2020, 2, 1), "mmyy")

'set counter for Do While ... Loop
counter = 0

'set condition for exit Do While ... Loop
wsExists = True

'declare arr for vals from sheets
Dim arr() As Variant

'start as empty array and redim in Do While ... Loop
arr = Array()

Do While wsExists 'loop will end on first ws as "mmyy" that does not exist

    'create string for each sheet
    wsName = Format(DateSerial(2020, 2 + counter, 1), "mmyy")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    'try to set ws to sheets(wsName), if it does not exist, error will be thrown
    Set ws = wbOpen.Sheets(wsName)
    
    'if sheets(wsName) does not exist, Err.Number will be <> 0
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        
        'no more sheets, exit loop by setting wsExists to False
        wsExists = False
        On Error GoTo 0
            
    Else
        
        'resize arr and preserve previous adds
        ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
        
        'add latest value to arr
        arr(UBound(arr)) = ws.Range("AA208").Value
        
    End If
    
    'increment to move to next "mmyy"
    counter = counter + 1

Loop

'close wbOpen, not needed anymore
wbOpen.Close False

'now we want to loop through all values in arr except the last 11 (we want rolling year sums, after all)
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 11

    'write data away in Range("J99") (Sheets("Sheet1")?) and rows below
    
    '''wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(99 + i, "I").Value = DateSerial(2020, 2 + i, 1)
    '''wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(99 + i, "I").NumberFormat = "mmyy"
    
    'in order to get sum of arr(0) through to arr(11) and then incremented by i each time:
        'we need to transpose the arr, wrap the transposed arr inside an index,
        'and for ROWS generate an array like {1,2,3,...,10,11,12} each time incremented by i through "Evaluate(ROW(1:12))" etc.
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(99 + i, "J").Value = Application.Sum(Application.Index(Application.Transpose(arr), Evaluate("ROW(" & (1 + i) & ":" & (12 + i) & ")"), 0))

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a much better way to do this conceptually. I thought a do while might work but did not think to get all values before looping through the array. I am implementing now. This is much appreciated.